# Table headers with arbitrary locations in Github flavored markdown

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

In the gfm documentation, the examples for tables always have the table headers at the top.

```
| foo | hello |
| --- | ----- |
| bar | test  |
```

[image: preview of table with header at top]

Is there a way to place the headers in arbitrary locations, for example to have headers on the top and side? This can be done using HTML to make the table, however is there a solution to this without using HTML?

[image: preview of table with header on left side and top]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this without using HTML.